# Как построить правило RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день, помогите построить правило RewriteRule

Мне нужно, чтобы при обращению к серверу по адресу - сайт/1 и до сайт/9999999, сайт/a и до сайт/z (то есть весь латинский алфавит, может быть и комбинация типа "frt").

Всё отсылало на одну страницу, но если открывают другую страницу сайта например .html или php, то открывалась эта страница.

Comment: вроде справился - 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9]$ lilurl.php [L]
Поправьте что не так

Comment: Поправляю: Ваше выражение позволяет только один символ после слэша. Надо так:  

    ^[a-z0-9]+$

Comment: делал для этого сайта - like-all.ru
Ваш способ не помог. Сделал по своему. но+ добавил по совету, я забыл про него )

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев:

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9]+$ lilurl.php [L]
```